# Nestjs with postgres and redis on docker connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, redis, nestjs

I've dockerize nestjs app with postgres and redis.
How can I fix this issue?
Postgres and redis are refusing tcp connections.
This is docker-compose.yml and console result.
I am using typeorm and @nestjs/bull for redis.

[image: docker-compose.yml]
[image: docker-compose.yml-2]

[image: result]

Hope much help.
Thanks

Comment: Assuming the nextjs app is running on the host machine, changing both service's network mode to "host" should work. Readup more [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

Answer (score 0):

When using `docker-compose`, the containers do not necessarily need to specify the network they are in since they can reach each other from the container name (e.g. `postgres`, `redis` in your case) because they are in the same network. See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more info.

Also, `expose` doesn't do any operation and it is redundant. Since you specify `ports`, it should be more than enough to tell `Docker` which ports of the container are exposed and bound to which ports of the host.

For `redis-alpine`, the startup command is `redis-server` and it is not necessary to specify it again. Also, the environment you specified is redundant in this case.

Try the following `docker-compose.yaml` with all of the above suggestions added:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=lighthouse

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 6379:6379
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, Eranga
Thanks for your kind reply.
I've tried following your answer but still same issue.
Could you help me more?
Thank you.

Comment: I believe your nest application is running in your machine locally. Not in a docker container? Also, could you check whether `postgres` and `redis` are running as containers in your machine? What is the output of `docker container ls`?

Comment: I added a small change to the file. I made `db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` --> `./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/`. Could you try now?

Comment: I have tried with `./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` but same.

Comment: Are you running the NestJS app in your local machine inside a docker container?

Comment: yes, I am running nestjs app on local and will deploy aws fargate

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS Fargate. But the problem you're having is you have your NestJS inside a docker container that is not in the same network as `redis` or `postgres`. To make it work in your local, you need to change where you specify the host of `redis` and `postgres` from `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) to `host.docker.internal`. Then it will work for you in your machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230257/discussion-between-yamata-tadashi-and-eranga-heshan).